# Sending outlook calendar event using codeigniter

Tags: php, email, outlook, codeigniter-3

I want to send calendar event on outlook using codeigniter 3.

I have this code.

```
    $organizer          = 'John Doe';
    $organizer_email    = 'xxx@xxx.com';
    $location           = "Park";
    $date               = '20180122';
    $date2               = '20180123';
    $startTime          = '0100';
    $endTime            = '0900';
    $subject            = 'Test';
    $desc               = 'Email Testing';

    $headers =  'From: Peter <xxxx@xxx.com>';
    $headers .= 'Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n';
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";

    $message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n
                X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Manila
                VERSION:2.0\r\n
                PRODID:-//Deathstar-mailer//theforce/NONSGML v1.0//EN\r\n
                METHOD:REQUEST\r\n
                BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n
                UID:" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) . "xxxx.com\r\n
                DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z\r\n
                DTSTART:".$date."T".$startTime."00Z\r\n
                DTEND:".$date2."T".$endTime."00Z\r\n
                SUMMARY:".$subject."\r\n
                ORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."\r\n
                LOCATION:".$location."\r\n
                DESCRIPTION:".$desc."\r\n
                ".$recp."
                END:VEVENT\r\n
                END:VCALENDAR\r\n";


    mail($toRecipients, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But instead I received something like this

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17W94.png)

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: where is screenshot?

Comment: Oh sorry. I edited the question. There is the screenshot. :)